# How do you strip the attachments from AWS SES-SNS incoming emails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

My problem statement is as follows:
I have configured AWS SES to receive emails on a subdomain. SES then send a notification to our web application via SNS. Now, SNS has a 150kb limit and therefore any emails with an attachment of sive>150kb is bounced.

My question is:
Is there a way to strip the SES email of the attachments before dispatching through SNS?

One solution is to save the attachments in S3, but we have absolutely no use for the attachments at this point and would prefer not incurring additional S3 costs for nothing. I have looked at multiple AWS documentation and have not been able to find a solution. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no direct way or configuration to achieve this. One workaround is to trigger a simple event driven Lambda function to extract an attachment from an email and discard it.